# Why we can not define method or class name as a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why we can not define method or class name as a string ?

I was trying to use & in a method name, in normal name it was throwing error, So i tried to use method name in a string like as:

```
def 'order_date_&_time'(self, obj):
        return obj.created_at
```

But it again showing another error(SyntaxError: invalid syntax).

> So Why i can not define method or class name as a string ?

Comment: Because compilers expect an **identifier**, not a **string literal**.... How would you call that method? like `'order'(1)`? Then what if a string would be callable itself?

Comment: Why do you want to use an ampersand instead of normal English words anyway (for an identifier)? `&` has special meaning in Python (bitwise AND) and using whole words is considered to be clearer

Comment: Because language specs says that. And as all languages I know have lexical rules for their identifiers, I just assume there should be a good reason for it - well I know the reason, source code must be parsed and parsers need a lexical definition for identifiers. You can try to build a language that accept any string for its identifier, but good luck with it because parsing will certainly be *interesting*...

Answer (score 3):

Function names need to follow the same syntax as identifiers do. Identifiers in Python follow a certain rule which does not allow an identifier to start with a symbol such as `'`. The accepted form of identifiers is clearly defined in the corresponding [section of the reference manual.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

You can't because the grammar rule defined for identifiers just doesn't allow it, simple as that.

Identifiers are meant to be readable, that's why characters such as `&` are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The python grammar is not defined this way

Take a look at this lecture about grammar (in CS) to get an idea about how a grammar is defined and why it must always be respected although it allows quite a bit of flexibility 
https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall2000/cs126/lectures/T3-4up.pdf